# Google Maps - Click and Zoom from a sidebar

Tags: google-maps, zooming, center

Hi hope someone can advise. I've been tasked with creating a map of various buildings and services. The map in question does work with categorisation coming via an XML feed and populating a floating sidebar with a list of buildings, click the names in the bar and the info window opens... The next step where I'm falling is the request to zoom in on that particualr location and centralise. So basically click it in list on map will zoom another couple of layers and then center the marker.

Suggestions? and help really appreciated.
http://nuweb.northumbria.ac.uk/google/campus.html

Answer (score 2):

Each sidebar entry currently calls `myclick()`:

```
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
}
```

so just add what you want to do to that function, something like the following, perhaps:

```
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew I'll give this a try, figure I need a variable for the zoom level too...

Comment: Absolutely spot on, cheers for the help.. was going round in circle with new google.maps.getZoom(15) in an effort to make a variable... didn't need to. Massive thanks